# Azure Function App Only Runs When I Open the Azure Portal

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have recently Created an Azure PowerShell Function from the portal. The function is setup to trigger every day at 4 PM. This works fine when I am logged in to the Portal but when In active in or if my laptop is shutdown, it does not trigger.

Below is the function.json which i tried,

schedule: 0 0 16 * * *

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This types issue basically happens in Azure Functions with Consumption plans, So I would suggest you to  use App service plan or Premium Plan where you use Settings called **`Always On`** like below:

[image]

It prevents the function app from being idled out due to inactivity

Comment: I use  App service plan with Free Tier F1, i gone through the article which says even if it is F1 it will trigger on schedule time. Is it true ?